# ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: owl_parse/4 (DWIM could not find correct goal)

Tags: ros, knowrobtutorials, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am new to knowrob and I have been following the knowrob tutorials. I am trying to do the Reasoning about objects tutorials and when I enter the command owl_parse('owl/ccrl2_map_objects.owl', false, false, true). I get this error: ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: owl_parse/4 (DWIM could not correct goal). I am using ros fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

I think I have installed all the required dependencies because I can rosmake knowrob successfully. I have entered all the commands under tutorial knowrob basics successfully except for the following two:

1. When I enter  **owl_has(A, rdf:type, knowrob:'Drawer'), add_object_with_children(A, $C)**. I don't get a small additional window to the visualisation canvas that contains control routines.
2. When I enter  **rdf_has(A, rdf:type, knowrob:'Drawer'), display_information_for(A, $C).** I get **ERROR: jpl_call/4: method 'displayInfoFor/1' does not exist (the class or object has no public methods with the given name and quantity of parameters).**

I then moved on to the Reasoning about objects tutorials and did the first two steps
**roscd knowrob_basics_tutorial** and
**rosrun rosprolog rosprolog knowrob_basics_tutorial**

But when I enter the third step: **owl_parse('owl/ccrl2_map_objects.owl', false, false, true)**

I get this error: **ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: owl_parse/4 (DWIM could not correct goal)**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76828/error:-toplevel:-undefined-procedure:-owl_parse/4-(dwim-could-not-find-correct-goal)/) by [HiroCollins](https://answers.ros.org/users/6334/hirocollins/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-09-05

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2013-09-05**:
Please post the commands you have entered, the problem is hard to guess otherwise. Have you checked if all dependencies of your package are correct and if rosmake of the package has succeeded?

**Comment by [HiroCollins](https://answers.ros.org/users/6334/hirocollins/) on 2013-09-05**:
I have edited my question. Hope it helps.

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2013-09-05**:
Have you installed KnowRob from source as explained here? http://knowrob.org/installation#installation_from_source

**Comment by [HiroCollins](https://answers.ros.org/users/6334/hirocollins/) on 2013-09-05**:
I had a problem installing knowrob from source as explained in the link you provided but I managed to install it as part of roboearth_stack as explained here http://wiki.ros.org/roboearth_stack

**Comment by [micpalmia](https://answers.ros.org/users/6343/micpalmia/) on 2013-10-08**:
Any news about this? I get the same error.
I guess the problem is some missing dependency in knowrob_basics_tutorial, as the same function works running mod_vis in rosprolog.

**Comment by [HiroCollins](https://answers.ros.org/users/6334/hirocollins/) on 2013-10-22**:
Never got an answer to this problem. I moved on to something else. micpalmia did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try to update the knowrob_tutorials package. Did you get any error messages or warnings when starting KnowRob with 'rosrun rosprolog rosprolog knowrob_basics_tutorial'? There should not be any, and errors during startup will lead to other weird errors later on, so they should be debugged first.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2013-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1